# Вывод даты из базы и подсчет строк где втстречаются эти даты

Tags: php, mysqli

В таблице mysql есть поле где хранится дата. и это дата встречается в этой таблице по несколько раз. Как в PHP вывести каждую дату и рядом с ним количество т е сколько раз встречается это дата в данной таблице. Например

2017-01-01

2017-01-01

2017-01-02

2017-02-25

2017-02-25

2017-02-25

хотелось бы вывести на страницу таким образом. 
ДАТА**************Кол-во
2017-01-01    -   2

2017-01-02    -   1

2017-02-25    -   3

А данный код выводит общее количество записей т е в моем случае 6

```
$result100 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  prdate, COUNT(*) FROM priem WHERE 
doctor_uid=$uidforfaq GROUP BY  prdate ;")  or 
die("<p>Не удается выбрать запись из базы данных</p>". mysqli_error($con));
$rowcount2 = mysqli_num_rows($result100);
echo $rowcount2 ;  
?>
```

В самом mySQL работает так как надо
через такой запрос

```
SELECT prdate, COUNT(*) FROM priem WHERE doctor_uid = 1
```

prdate       COUNT(*)
2017-06-24   2

т е ДАТА-КОЛИЧЕСТВО а вот как вывести его черех  PHP в браузер в таком виде ?

Comment: Вы уверены что у вас даты без времени хранятся? То что `group by` возвращает 6 записей означает что все эти даты чем то отличаются друг от друга.

Comment: Прошу прощения Arnial неправильно оказывается написал, всё исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вывести в php в таком же формате, как у вас получилось в Mysql, используйте этот код

```
$a = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT prdate, COUNT(*) FROM priem WHERE 
                   doctor_uid = 1 ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($a);
echo $row['prdate'] . " " . $row['COUNT(*)'];
```

Comment: Как раз то что надо спасибо Вам,  Дима Нпц

Comment: Можно ещё вопрос если вытаскивать из базы без цикла т е без while он всю таблицу будет читать ? или же нет ?

Comment: Тут не подскажу, сам еще только учусь

Comment: По любому спасибо Вам огромное ! Желаю дальнейших успехов

Comment: Спасибо. Если я правильно вас понял, то в цикл нужно обернуть $row = mysqli_fetch_array($a);
echo $row['prdate'] . " " . $row['COUNT(*)'];

Comment: В общих чертах сделал так <?php $a = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  prdate, COUNT(*) FROM priem WHERE doctor_uid = $id GROUP BY prdate")  or 
die("<p>Не удается выбрать запись из базы данных</p>". mysqli_error($con));

while ($row500 = mysqli_fetch_array($a)) { 
echo $row500['prdate'] . " " . $row500['COUNT(*)']; }?>